# Infinite 360 deg 3d rotation of an isometric shape with nested hover animation

Tags: html, css

I try to understand how to animate a 3d object with css. Right now i have an isometric type of shape that shows its inside when it's hovered. But additionally i want to animate this isometric shape to turn around 360deg as 3d shape infinite. I've been fiddling with its transform for each box but it doesn't work at all.

Can anyone help me and give some tips or explanations how i can achieve this?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cube {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 50% auto;
}

.outterstack .left {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 250px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg) skewX(-30deg) scaleY(0.864);
  background-color: grey;
}

.outterstack .right {
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 250px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(-30deg) scaleY(0.864);
  position: relative;
  bottom: 250px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.outterstack .up {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(210deg) skew(-30deg) scaleY(0.864);
  position: relative;
  bottom: 350px;
  background-color: violet;
}

.insidestack .left {
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 150px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg) skewX(-30deg) scaleY(0.864);
  background-color: black;
}

.insidestack .right {
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 150px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(-30deg) scaleY(0.864);
  position: relative;
  bottom: 149px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.insidestack .up {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(210deg) skew(-30deg) scaleY(0.864);
  position: relative;
  bottom: 249px;
  background-color: green;
}

.one,
.two,
.three,
.oneins,
.twoins,
.threeins,
.four {
  position: relative;
  left: 150px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.one {
  top: 150px;
  z-index: 7;
}

.oneins {
  bottom: 400px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.two {
  bottom: 740px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.twoins {
  bottom: 1200px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.three {
  bottom: 1630px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.threeins {
  bottom: 2120px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.four {
  bottom: 2520px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cube:hover .one {
  top: 150px;
  z-index: 7;
}

.cube:hover .oneins {
  bottom: 400px;
  z-index: 6;
}

.cube:hover .two {
  bottom: 650px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.cube:hover .twoins {
  bottom: 1200px;
  z-index: 4;
}

.cube:hover .three {
  bottom: 1450px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.cube:hover .threeins {
  bottom: 2000px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.cube:hover .four {
  bottom: 2250px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cube">
  <div class="outterstack one">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="up"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="insidestack oneins">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="up"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="outterstack two">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="up"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="insidestack twoins">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="up"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="outterstack three">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="up"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="insidestack threeins">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="up"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="outterstack four">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="up"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: to able to rotate this you need to first finish the missing sides from the back because actually the shape is buitl using 3 sides and you are missing 2 (3 if we count the bottom one)

Comment: i get what you meant  but i tried this too but when i trying to rotate it it still rotate like a  2d shape do i need to add anything else to this before rotate it?. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with an css @keyframes animation, but then you need two more side surfaces for each cuboid. Instead the 'up' surfaces from the inner cuboids are not necessary since they are not visible.

**Working example:**

```css
.cube {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(-17deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-17deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 360deg);
  }
}

.insidestack {
  margin-left: 50px;
}


                                   /* positioning of the cuboids */
.outterstack,
.insidestack {
  position: relative;
  transition: top 1s;
}

.one {
  top: 0;
}

.oneins {
  top: 5px;
}

.two {
  top: 110px;
}

.twoins {
  top: 115px;
}

.three {
  top: 220px;
}

.threeins {
  top: 225px;
}

.four {
  top: 330px;
}


                                   /* positioning when hovered */
.cube:hover .oneins {
  top: 105px;
}

.cube:hover .two {
  top: 210px;
}

.cube:hover .twoins {
  top: 315px;
}

.cube:hover .three {
  top: 420px;
}

.cube:hover .threeins {
  top: 525px;
}

.cube:hover .four {
  top: 630px;
}


                                   /* positioning of the surfaces */
.side,
.flat {
  position: absolute;
}

.outterstack .front {
  transform: translateZ(125px);
}

.outterstack .back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(125px);
}

.outterstack .right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(125px);
}

.outterstack .left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(125px);
}

.outterstack .up {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(125px);
}

.insidestack .front {
  transform: translateZ(75px);
}

.insidestack .back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(75px);
}

.insidestack .right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(75px);
}

.insidestack .left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(75px);
}


                                   /* styling of the surfaces */
.outterstack .side {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: grey;
}

.outterstack .flat {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: violet;
}

.insidestack .side {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

.insidestack .front,
.insidestack .back {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.insidestack .right,
.insidestack .left {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="cube">
  <div class="outterstack one">
    <div class="side front"></div>
    <div class="side back"></div>
    <div class="side right"></div>
    <div class="side left"></div>
    <div class="flat up"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="insidestack oneins">
    <div class="side front"></div>
    <div class="side back"></div>
    <div class="side right"></div>
    <div class="side left"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="outterstack two">
    <div class="side front"></div>
    <div class="side back"></div>
    <div class="side right"></div>
    <div class="side left"></div>
    <div class="flat up"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="insidestack twoins">
    <div class="side front"></div>
    <div class="side back"></div>
    <div class="side right"></div>
    <div class="side left"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="outterstack three">
    <div class="side front"></div>
    <div class="side back"></div>
    <div class="side right"></div>
    <div class="side left"></div>
    <div class="flat up"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="insidestack threeins">
    <div class="side front"></div>
    <div class="side back"></div>
    <div class="side right"></div>
    <div class="side left"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="outterstack four">
    <div class="side front"></div>
    <div class="side back"></div>
    <div class="side right"></div>
    <div class="side left"></div>
    <div class="flat up"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: God answer. I believe that you don't so many keyframes, just the first and the last one

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I deleted the unnecessary keyframes...

Comment: thanks for the answer i think i am starting to get how people design 3d object using css, but i want to ask, i usually see people use perspective in their parent div when creating a 3d object using css, does by adding that give an effect to the object? i know that by adding the perspective it show a much clear of the 3d object view but i am still a bit confused because sometime i used it, it's not showing any change at all, thanks

Answer (score 1):

take a look at my code. i hope this helps you understand cube rotation.

```js
var current = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {}, 1000);
function rotateX() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    current++;
    document.getElementById("cube").style.transform = "rotate3d(1, 0, 0, "+current+"deg)";
    
    if (current > 360) {
      current = 0;
    }
  }, 30);
}
function rotateY() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    current++;
    document.getElementById("cube").style.transform = "rotate3d(0, 1, 0, "+current+"deg)";
    
    if (current > 360) {
      current = 0;
    }
  }, 30);
}
function rotateZ() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    current++;
    document.getElementById("cube").style.transform = "rotate3d(0, 0, 1, "+current+"deg)";
    
    if (current > 360) {
      current = 0;
    }
  }, 30);
}
rotateX();
```

```css
#cube {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.side {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    backface-visibility: inherit;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}
.front {
    background: rgba(90,90,90,.7);
    transform: translateZ(50px);
}
.back {
    background: rgba(0,210,0,.7);
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(50px);
}
.right {
    background: rgba(210,0,0,.7);
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px);
}
.left {
    background: rgba(0,0,210,.7);
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
}
.top {
    background: rgba(210,210,0,.7);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);
}
.bottom {
    background: rgba(210,0,210,.7);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
}
```

```html
<div id="cube" class="transition-all" style="transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 1, 45deg);">
  <div class="side front">front</div>
  <div class="side back">back</div>
  <div class="side right">right</div>
  <div class="side left">left</div>
  <div class="side top">top</div>
  <div class="side bottom">bottom</div>
</div>

<div style="margin-top: 50px">
<button onclick="rotateX()">rotate X</button>
<button onclick="rotateY()">rotate Y</button>
<button onclick="rotateZ()">rotate Z</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You should add a hint why you used javascript since the OP asked for a css solution. Something like "this will not work just with css - you need js"

Comment: The script simply changes the `rotate3d` attribute by the time interval. You can change it manually.